# Locked my sa user out

Tags: sql-server, security, authentication, windows-authentication

So I was trying to change some settings in my Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2019. I change the login mode from mixed (Windows and SQL authentication) to only Windows and now I am not able to login with my sa account and I don't have another account which has admin rights.

What should I do? Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this.

One option is to login to the windows machine as a local administrator, start SQL Server in single user mode (-m startup switch) and you will now be able to get into your SQL server as a sysadmin using Windows authentication.

The other option is to quite simply change back to mixed mode by modifying the registry in windows directly (not supported). On my machine, the registry path for a named instance (named "a") is: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.A\MSSQLServer. And the value for mixed authentication is LoginMode: 2.

Comment: Here's the documentation for the first option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/connect-to-sql-server-when-system-administrators-are-locked-out?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I had forgotten the single mode method, though honestly that still requires a reboot of the services. Your answer is short and sweet, hence removed my answer.

Comment: I used the second option and it worked like magic and it's very simple

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to access the server that SQL Server is hosted on then you can use your local Windows account to gain access and change the setting back. If you do not have that level of access, you could contact the administrators of the server and ask them to change it back for you.

Once you are on the server do the following to change the setting:

- Open SQL Server Management Studio as you would normally
- Log in using Windows Authentication.
- Once logged in, right click the server and choose **Properties**.
- Click the **Security** page.
- Under `Server Authentication` select the `SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode` radio button.
- Click `OK` to save your changes.

For more information, see the documentation for [Change Server Authentication Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I am sorry but I am new to this. I am the only person who is responsible for this. I have created the server using windows server express or something like that. Now I am inside my local windows account, what should I do?

Comment: I have updated my answer with a guide.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the update. However, it didn't work it kept giving me error about that I don't have permission. I was able to solve it by going to registry and change the login value from 1 to 2. Thanks a lot anyways

Comment: @Kashan editing the registry is risky and unsupported by Microsoft. But glad you got the system up.  I would test bounce it at least once to see if your registry edit has any other effects and to be on the safe side!

Comment: Take all DB backup before thinking of restarting the services.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin impossible if no one can access the server.

Comment: @clifton_h I am suggesting to take DB backup if the issue is solved and he can access databases after changing the registry.